# Scope resolution operator being used twice

Tags: c++, class, constructor, namespaces, name-lookup

```
namespace libzerocoin {

//Commitment class
Commitment::Commitment::Commitment(const IntegerGroupParams* p,
                               const Bignum& value): params(p), contents(value) {
this->randomness = Bignum::randBignum(params->groupOrder);
this->commitmentValue = (params->g.pow_mod(this->contents, params->modulus).mul_mod(
                         params->h.pow_mod(this->randomness, params->modulus), params->modulus));
}
```

I just encountered this function definition on [GitHub](https://github.com/zcoinofficial/zcoin/blob/master/src/libzerocoin/Commitment.cpp#L19).

I assume that the second and the third "Commitment" refer to the class name and constructor, but I can't figure out the meaning of the first. I am sure that it does not refer to the namespace because that name is different. I have seen the scope resolution operator being used twice in examples, but those refer to nested namespaces.

Comment: Even class B {   B(); }; B::B::B::B() {} compiles with gcc and clang but MSVC has issues. Interesting. Maybe injected type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C++ classes have the feature of having their name injected into their scope ([[class]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#2)):

> The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself;
>   this is known as the *injected-class-name*. For purposes of access
>   checking, the *injected-class-name* is treated as if it were a public
>   member name.

And the code snippet you showed makes use of it. In certain contexts `Commitment::Commitment` names the class itself, and in others names the c'tor. Only the last `Commitment(`, where you open the parentheses, begins the c'tor definition.

And it can look much much worse:

```
struct foo {
    foo();
};

foo::foo::foo::foo() = default;
```

Which you can see is valid C++ <kbd>[Live](https://ideone.com/tA1MYx)</kbd>.

Comment: what's the purpose of this strange feature?

Comment: @DevNull - I'd wager it's to smooth certain sharp edges of generic code. But honestly, I never stumbled upon it.