# Why class::class::class::staticClassMember() compiles (in C++)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-methods, sfinae, name-lookup

I must have missed something in C++ specification because I can't explain why the following code compiles successfully:

```
class MyClass { static void fun(); };
int main() { MyClass::MyClass::MyClass::fun(); }
```

Could somebody point me to the standard or just explain me the semantics? I would guess that only one `MyClass::` is allowed. Two `MyClass::MyClass::` should cause error. Experimenting with MS Visual C++ 2017 and GNU C++ 6.2.0 I realized that any count of `MyClass::` is allowed.

It is not only a theoretical question. I wanted to use SFINAE and condition compilation with existence of a sub-class. Worked good until the base class has the same name as the sub-class:

```
template <class T> void callWorkout() { T::SubClass::workout(); }
struct X { struct SubClass { static void workout(); }; };
struct Y { /*empty*/ };
struct SubClass { static void workout(); };

int main() {
  callWorkout<X>();  // works fine - compiled
  callWorkout<Y>();  // works "fine" - not compiled, no SubClass in Y
  callWorkout<SubClass>();  // ooops? - still compiled, there is no 'SubClass' in SubClass
}
```

My question has two parts:

- What is the exact semantics of `MyClass::MyClass::`?
- How can I fix the above example not to compile `callWorkout<SubClass>()`? (I tried to add `sizeof(typename T::SubClass)` but surprisingly it compiles also for `T=SubClass`)

Comment: Basically this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575074/scope-resolution-operator-being-used-twice/47575256

Comment: @StoryTeller Great! That answers perfectly the first bullet.  Any idea on the second one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the [injected class name of `MyClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575074/scope-resolution-operator-being-used-twice/47575256). And you can verify it's not `T` by simply using `std::is_same_v<T, typename T::SubClass>` in a SFINAE conditional.

```
template <class T>
auto callWorkout() -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T, typename T::SubClass>>
{ T::SubClass::workout(); }
```

If you don't need SFINAE (because you aren't trying to control overload resolution), then a `static_assert` with a descriptive custom message can also do nicely.