# Why does declaration with double identifier compile

Tags: c++

I was reviewing someone else's code and came across the equivalent of this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void bar();
};

// Notice that there are two Foo::
inline void Foo::Foo::bar() {
    std::cout << "Why does this compile" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Why does `Foo::Foo::bar` compile? Shouldn't it be necessary for it to be `Foo::bar`?

Comment: `Foo` is injected into the `Foo` namespace.  You'll find that `Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo::bar()` also compiles.

Comment: [Why are redundant class name qualifiers allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423380/why-are-redundant-class-name-qualifiers-allowed) and [Why is there injected class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name). Also [Scope resolution operator being used twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575074/scope-resolution-operator-being-used-twice)